# What is the Logical NOT (!) doing here?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Could someone help me understand what is going on or what the purpose of this logical NOT in this for loop?

```
var homeOwnerAssoc = false;


for (ixIrc = 0; !homeOwnerAssoc && ixIrc < SummaryOfRisks.RiskCode.length; ixIrc++) {
    homeOwnerAssoc = SummaryOfRisks.RiskCode[ixIrc] == "FUBAR";
}
```

What is the `!homeOwnerAssoc` part doing?

My assumption is that its checking that its set to false? because when I read up on Logical NOT (!) it would flip it to true.. That's where I am getting confused.

Thanks!

Comment: The full expression is `!homeOwnerAssoc && ixIrc < SummaryOfRisks.RiskCode.length`, so if `homeOwnerAssoc = false`, then it checks `ixIrc < SummaryOfRisks.RiskCode.length`

Comment: it's a short circuit/ an early exit of the loop.

Comment: _"What is the Logical NOT (!) doing here?"_ => _" its checking that its set to false"_! This question is unclear for me.

Comment: as Nina S said, it's a short circuit evaluation of the loop so that if the `predicate` evaluates to false - or in your example  !homerOwnerAssociate - the second part after && does not get evaluated

Comment: Hey everyone, thank you, that makes sense. It's more or less what I was thinking.